# Is O(n) a proper class or a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Is $O(n)$ as the collection of all functions that are bounded above by $n$ a proper class or just a set?

What about $O(\infty)$?

Comment: Are those functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, or $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ or what?

Comment: I was thinking $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ I guess I should have written $O(x)$ in this case. I'm having some difficulty getting my head around this, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since $\Bbb R$ is a set, we know that $\Bbb{R\times R}$ is a set, so $\mathcal P(\mathbb{R\times R})$ is a set.

Therefore the collection of all functions from $\Bbb R$ to itself is a set. In particular any definable subcollection of a set is a set. For example, all the functions which are $O(n)$ or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! Understanding this answer cleared up many things.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible ways to define it, but on reasonable way to define it is like so:

$O(g(n))$ is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb R$ where there exist $k, N\in\mathbb R$ such that whenever $n>N$, $f(n)<k g(n)$. (i.e. $f$ is eventually *bounded above* by $g$)

That means $O(n)$ is the set of functions that are bounded above by the function $g(n)=n$.

$O(\infty)$ would be the set of all functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, since everything is bounded above by $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, you have a proper set.

Comment: I don't think that I met "proper set" before. :-)

Comment: You mean a set. Not a proper class.

Comment: A set, not a general class.

Comment: To drive the point home, if you say "proper set", what is an "improper set"? On the other hand, every set is a class, so it's quite clear what an improper class means and what a proper class means.

Comment: as opposed to a class.

Comment: But a set is a class. If $A$ is a set, then the class $\{x\mid x\in A\}$ is a set which happens to be equal to $A$ itself.

Comment: Ah, but a set *is* a class. A *proper* class is a class that is not a set. A "proper set" is...what?